# Where can we register for iOS developer program outside of US

Tags: ios, publishing

This is not directly programming related but it is about publishing an iPhone app.

If you develop and publish an iPhone app from a european country (Germany) do you still have to register for the developer account on this english website:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

And pay the fee in dollars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all iPhone developers worldwide go through the centralised US site, and fees are all payable in US dollars.  Later when you earn income from the App store, you are paid in your local currency, but prices are translated from Dollar prices (on a fixed rate rather than fluctuating one).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to. No big deal though, they'll take your credit card.

When you later upload your program to iTunes, you'll be able to select where you want it to be available.